# How can i mark an EKEvent as complete?

Tags: ios, calendar, ekevent, ekeventkit, ekeventstore

How can i let the user to mark an EKEvent as complete?
I am currently fetching the events for a date and showing it in the UITableView.

```
// Fetching events happening in the next 24 hours with a predicate, limiting to the default calendar
- (NSArray *)fetchEventsForDate:(NSDate*)startDate
{
    [self.eventsList removeAllObjects];
    // endDate is 1 day = 60*60*24 seconds = 86400 seconds from startDate
    NSDate *endDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400];


    NSMutableDictionary *eventsDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1024];
    NSDate* currentStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:startDate];

//    int seconds_in_year = 60*60*24*365;
    int seconds_in_day = 60*60*24;


    // enumerate events by one year segment because iOS do not support predicate longer than 4 year !
    //while ([currentStart compare:endDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {

        NSDate* currentFinish = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:seconds_in_day sinceDate:currentStart];

        if ([currentFinish compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
            currentFinish = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:endDate];
        }
        NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:currentStart endDate:currentFinish calendars:nil];
        [eventStore enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:predicate
                                          usingBlock:^(EKEvent *event, BOOL *stop) {
                                              if (event) {
                                                  [eventsDict setObject:event forKey:event.eventIdentifier];
                                              }
                                          }];       

    NSArray *events = [eventsDict allValues];

    return events;
}
```

I want the user to tap the event cell to mark it as complete.

What can be change (any tag or bool) to update and save that EKEvent to show it as complete event in future?

```
[self.eventStore saveEvent: myUpatedEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
```

I explored

> `event.status, event.refresh, event.organizer, event.availability, etc.`

but none was useful.

I tried `EKEventAvailability` as

```
  [event setAvailability:EKEventAvailabilityUnavailable];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSLog(@"Event Availbility:%d",event.availability); // It always returned -1;
        [self.eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Save Event errorDiscription:%@",error.description);
        }
```

but it was not updating and returning -1 (`EKEventAvailabilityNotSupported`) and updating.

Please suggest!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `availability` of the tapped event as `EKEventAvailabilityUnavailable`.
If the event is completed, logically it is unavailable isn't it?

```
But if the event’s calendar does not support availability settings,
this property’s value is `EKEventAvailabilityNotSupported.`
```

**EDIT:**
We can alternately, use `eventIdentifier` property of EKEvent.

This is a **unique identifier for the event. (read-only)** We can store it locally or in CoreData when user taps on an event and use for future purposes.

Comment: I tried that but it was returning `EKEventAvailabilityNotSupported`,
and it was not even updating. Please share how to update that.

Comment: `   [event setAvailability:EKEventAvailabilityUnavailable];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSLog(@"Event Availbility:%d",event.availability);
        [self.eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Save Event errorDiscription:%@",error.description);
        } `




I tried this but it was not updating and returning -1 always.